# application with setup file with out SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, installation

I have a windows application which is uses SQL Server as its database. For this application I want to create a setup file for other desktops, but I don't want to install SQL Server on each and every client.

Can you please suggest how to create Windows application with local storage setup file without installing any databases or framework libraries?

Comment: You shouldn't indent your paragraphs with spaces like a letter, here it gets treated as a code block.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install SQL Server on each client - you can simply install it on a central server then all the clients can connect to and use the same instance.

If this is not a good option because each client must have its own storage locally then you can look to use something like [SQL Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142.aspx), which is a very cut down version of SQL Server that doesn't require installation and runs inproc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SQL Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142.aspx). The database is stored in a file that you carry with the product rather than requiring a database server.

If this is just for "settings" then consider storing it in the [user's application data](http://dotnetdud.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/how-to-retrieve-application-data-folder.html) as a simple XML file.